# How can I make acknowledgement the same style as other sections in report class

Tags: table-of-contents, acknowledgements

Now I am writing a thesis and want to add acknowledgement, basically I want it looks the same as other section titles in contents, and the word "Acknowledgement" on the top centre of that page.

My Acknowledgement looks like:
[image]
[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[style]{fncychap}
%\linespread{1.6}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mathtools,array,booktabs}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}  % "absolute value" macro
\newcommand\FWHM{\mathrm{FWHM}}
\newcommand\FROG{\mathrm{FROG}}

%\ChNumVar{\fontsize{76}{80}\usefont{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}\selectfont}
%\ChTitleVar{\raggedleft\Large\sffamily\bfseries}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{image/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=40mm,bottom=45mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\title{ 
   {Simpler ultrashort pulse characterisation with a new type of frequency-resolved optical gating}\\
   {\large Imperial College London}\\
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{University.png}}
\end{figure}             
}
\author{Mingyang Zhang}
\date{20 September 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\newpage

\listoftables
\newpage

\section*{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapter/1.Introduction}

\chapter{Background}
\input{chapter/2.Background}

\chapter{Nonlinear Optics}
\input{chapter/3.NLO}

\chapter{Autocorrelation}
\input{chapter/4.Autocorrelation}

\chapter{Spectrometer}
\input{chapter/5.Spectrometer}

\chapter{Frequency-Resolved Optical Gating (FROG)}
\input{chapter/6.FROG}

\chapter{Experimental Device}
\input{chapter/7.Device}

\chapter{Data Analysis}
\input{chapter/8.Data}

\chapter{Performance}
\input{chapter/9.Performance}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{example}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Reference}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a chapter entry.

---

[image: mingyangzhangAcknowledgments]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,demo]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[style]{fncychap}
%\linespread{1.6}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mathtools,array,booktabs}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}  % "absolute value" macro
\newcommand\FWHM{\mathrm{FWHM}}
\newcommand\FROG{\mathrm{FROG}}

%\ChNumVar{\fontsize{76}{80}\usefont{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}\selectfont}
%\ChTitleVar{\raggedleft\Large\sffamily\bfseries}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{image/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=40mm,bottom=45mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\title{ 
       {Simpler ultrashort pulse characterisation with a new type of frequency-resolved optical gating}\\
          {\large Imperial College London}\\
%         \begin{figure}[h]% NEVER use a figure environment on a titlepage
              \centering
              {\includegraphics[scale=.1]{University.png}}
%         \end{figure}             
      }
      \author{Mingyang Zhang}
      \date{20 September 2016}

      \begin{document}

      \maketitle

      \tableofcontents

      \listoffigures

      \listoftables

      \chapter*{Acknowledgement}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgement}

      \chapter{Introduction}

      \chapter{Background}

      \chapter{Nonlinear Optics}

      \chapter{Autocorrelation}

      \chapter{Spectrometer}

      \chapter{Frequency-Resolved Optical Gating (FROG)}

      \chapter{Experimental Device}

      \chapter{Data Analysis}

      \chapter{Performance}

      \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
      \bibliography{example}
      %\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Reference} Will give wrong result


      \end{document}
```